# Drupal 7 Add Readmore to Basic Page

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal, I have requirement to add a readmore link to Basic Page content. That readmore trim the full content.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few 'read more' link modules, like this one: http://drupal.org/project/read_more

There is also the 'teaser' display mode, as on the front page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display suite to control how to use the read more. You can trim your text field and then show the read-more. The read more will link to the full content.With Display suite you can also change the label of the read more with [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds). I like this article detailing what you can do with Display Suite:

- [Building Fancy Teasers Without Custom Templates](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/display-suite-building-fancy-teasers-without-custom-templates)
- [Display suite videos that explain the functionality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjOG8dVcN4Y&feature=list_other&playnext=1&list=SP7E361A55994F1648)